# Schedule php script in xampp

Tags: php, windows, cron, xampp

I am using `xampp` on Windows Vista. I want to run a php script once every x minutes.

Is there any way in `xampp` to help facilitate this, or is using the Windows Task Scheduler the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in windows task schedular is the only way i think
in linux you can use cron